# Detect an imagination EEG signal

Tags: eeg, signal-detection

Is there an EEG brain signal that has specific features resulting from imagination? For example, if a subject sees a car and imagines that the car is moving left. Could we capture this signal and decrypt what was the person imagining?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is find in the literature, or construct and validate, a sound definition of "imagination".

Comment: @Krysta , Wow i was thinking that word does not need clarification !

Comment: In experimentation, *everything* needs a validated operational definition.

Comment: @Krysta , I'm sorry , you question seems hard  to explain abstract thing like `imagination` , at least for a  person who is specialist little far a way from cognitive science or neuroscience , but if you looking to the following [paper](http://icwww.epfl.ch/~gerstner/PUBLICATIONS/Millan04.pdf) , at page 8 the authors used the word `imagination` without definition , and what they did(which is explained in the same page ) are so close to what i want to do , thanks in advance.

Comment: @Learner lol you really know how to burn

Comment: @Learner I often bump in people that think some word does not need clarification. Being unfriendly to other people you're motivating me to push on your question being closed instead of helping you to clarify.

Comment: @TomášZato , I've never mean to being unfriendly to anyone , I'm apologia if this appear in my words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course. Most work with eeg and imagination focuses on the [inner voice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imagined_speech) and what people are telling themselves and thinking to themselves. Imagine (pun intended) if we could reach into the mind of a terrorist and as they think about plots. Its not really all that hard but its not at all covert at the moment (all the schizoiod type personalities can relax). With a bunch of [electrodes connected](http://www.katu.com/news/local/Washington-researchers-transfer-human-thoughts-over-the-Internet-221656251.html) to the brain we are able to transfer what one person's imagined actions into another persons head for execution. Its really crude at the moment but at some point it will revolutionize the way we think about communication, art, education and intimacy. Connecting to imagined visualizations would be simular only instead of involving the motor cortex it would work with the visual centers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! , but i have a few questions , Is this signal has known characteristics/features that we can use it in the [Brain computer interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain%E2%80%93computer_interface) , for example The P300 (or ERP signals in general )  signal could be extracted by the computers(Through signals processing and Artificial intelligence Techniques) , and there is  a wide BCI research based on it. but I'm does not see a researches in BCI that use the `imagination` or `inner voice` signals , is there a kind of hardness in dealing with those Signals in BCI ?

Comment: @Learner thank you for the additional questions i will respond as soon as possible but briefly: Motivational mechanisms (BAS) and prefrontal cortical activation contribute to recognition memory for emotional words. rTMS effect on performance and EEG (alpha band) measures, Self-Organizing Maps Based Thought Recognition
via EEG Brain Activity Monitoring

Comment: thought recognition is the keyword i didn't include in the paragraph which you can plug into google scholar.

Comment: @Learner was that one paper and keyword enough or would you like more?

Comment: Translation of Thought to Written Text While Composing edited by Michel Fayol, M. Denis Alamargot, Virginia Wise Berninger

Comment: I feel sceptic about that news message in answer.

Comment: @Learner http://www.newscientist.com/article/mg22429934.000-brain-decoder-can-eavesdrop-on-your-inner-voice.html#.VHkAANXF_7t